# Directory listing: 403 Forbidden nginx

Tags: nginx

Hello I started using nginx, set up the nginx.conf to my project folder C: / Projects.

I used (AutoIndex: on) to have a list of directories, but does not work

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;


    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        root C:\Project ;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        location / {
            autoindex on;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `autoindex on;` outside your location block

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile      on;


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root C:\Project ;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # moved here
    autoindex on; 
    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one of the `index` files present inside your `root` directory (or any subdirectory under `C:\Project` for that matter), the index page will be shown rather than the index of contents.

You may also want to check the permissions on all content under your `root`; they need to be readable by the user running your Nginx process.

Could be a number of different things; you'll need to clarify your questions in future with what you've tried and haven't tried.